# What/who are "toy soldiers"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, lyrics

There is a song called [Toy Soldiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Soldiers_(song)) by *Martika* of which a part of the lyrics goes:

> Step by step
> Heart to heart
> Left, right, left
> We all fall down
> Like toy soldiers
>
> Bit by bit
> Torn apart
> We never win
> But the battle wages on
> For toy soldiers

This song was later remade by *Eminem*, retaining the original chorus lyrics, but being renamed to **Like Toy Soldiers**.

What does this phrase mean? Who are the toy soldiers? I know the literal meaning - the toys - small soldiers - with which the children play, but I believe there is a deeper meaning to it.

Comment: Interpretation of literature is off-topic for this site, and once we've established that the phrase *toy soldiers* is being used literally here (which I think we have), the "deeper meaning" - if any - becomes a question of interpretation.

Comment: After watching _Bokurano_, _Martika's Toy Soldiers_ felt so much darker.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Like toy soldiers" does mean *disposable* and *easily knocked down*, but in each context the use of the phrase takes on additional connotations.

For Martika ([watch video](http://youtu.be/LvdLovAaYzM)), there seem to be multiple levels of meaning. First, there's the sense of young people in relationships being toy soldiers in that they often hurt each other (get knocked down), but keep going on. [Some](http://www.songmeanings.net/songs/view/16520/) have argued the toy soldiers are the men the singer is going after as she breaks one heart after another. There are also clear drug allusions in Martika's video. In this layer, those who are addicted to drugs are the toy soldiers. Ultimately, I think the song is about the loss of innocence—whether to drugs or bad relationships, or both. Using a childhood toy as a metaphor conveys this well.

Eminem ([watch video](http://youtu.be/dRhFg5Z9IKk)) didn't remake the song, but samples Martika's chorus as the chorus to his rap song. The following [definition from the Urban Dictionary](http://toy-soldier.urbanup.com/1106155) explains Eminem's use of the phrase:

> 1. **Toy Soldier**
>      Urban background, orginating on the streets and in hip-hop lyrics
> 2. A friend that's willing to go out and ride with you, no matter what the situation may be
> 3. A friend who has your back and is willing to give his life to ensure your protection (in essence, a friend that acts like a body guard)
>      *My dawg G-War is my toy soldier...he always got my back*

The song is about Eminem's attempts to deal with a violent feud in the rap community and the video depicts a member of Eminem's original group getting gunned down in a drive-by shooting.

Answer (score 7):

It means "toy soldiers" ie. the toy figures put in a line by children which are easy to knock over.  So poetically it also means unimportant or disposable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two perceptions :
The soldiers are used like toys .

The song is about a past relationship with a soldier. Unfortunately the soldier lost his life in a war  (notice the last scene in the video where she places a rose in his grave).